# How to open mongo console in WebStorm while meteor project is running?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, webstorm

I just installed meteor and running a simple app using the WebStorm.

Now I want to open the mongo console and not able to do it in WebStorm while the project is running. Any leads?

Comment: what way do you use to open mongo console in webStorm?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you aren't able to open the console.  I very rarely use the console anyways.  Consider adding mongol via: meteor add msavin:mongol You can just hit ctrl+m in the browser and an incredibly useful window appears where you can view and edit your collection.  [Mongol](https://github.com/msavin/Mongol)